# How to remove the top space in the grid view builder?

Tags: flutter, gridview, drop-down-menu, whitespace, padding

I am using a `GridView.Builder` to show some `Text` and `DropDown`. I also gave the `padding zero` in the `GridView.Builder`. But there is still some space at the top. I tried to provide `mainAxisExtent: 22` and the top space issue is solved, but it also reduced the dropdown's height. You can see the underline overlapped with the text in the `DropDown`. How should I remove the space At the top?

**K variables:**

```
const Color kBlack = Colors.black;
double kTextScale = Get.textScaleFactor;
double kWidth = Get.width;
double kHeight = Get.height;
```

**Code:**

```
Container(
    color: Colors.yellow,
    width: kWidth * 0.7,
    height: kHeight * 0.2,
    child: GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          mainAxisSpacing: 20,
          crossAxisSpacing: 20,
          crossAxisCount: 3),
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      itemCount: 7,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Row(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
              child: Text(
                "Sun",
                style: TextStyle(color: kBlack, fontSize: kTextScale * 14),
              ),
            ),
            DropdownButton(
              value: 0,
              items: shortBookViewModel.value
                  .map(
                    (value) => DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: value,
                      child: Text(
                        value.toString(),
                        style:
                            TextStyle(color: kBlack, fontSize: kTextScale * 14),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                  .toList(),
              onChanged: (value) {},
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: could you also include k variable?

Comment: @eamirho3ein I have included the k variables in the question. please take a look.

Comment: could you include an image and point it out the issue in that? @SenthurKumaran

Comment: You have to set childAspectRatio inside SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount.

Comment: try to wrap your Gridview builder with `MediaQuery.removePadding`